# jquery ajax error

Tags: jquery

I wrote a login form where on submit the user is supposed to logged in, but it is not working. please let me know where is the error is,
This is the form

```
<form id ="loginform_" action="">
    <a href=""id="slidedownclose">X</a>
    <h2> Login Form</h2>
    Username:<input type="text" id="uname" name="user_name"  /><br/><br/>
    Password:<input type="password" id="password" name="password" /><br/><br/>
    <input type ="submit" id ="log"  class="logclass" value="log in"/><br/><br/>
    <a id ="lost_password" href ="/frontend_dev.php/forgotpassword">Forgot Password </a>
</form>
```

this is the jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#loginform_").validate({
        rules: {
            user_name: "required",
            password: "required"
        }
    });
    $(".logclass").click(function()
    {
        var data =$("#loginform_").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/frontend_dev.php/login/new",
            data: data,
            success: function(){
                alert('success');
                window.location.replace("/frontend_dev.php/user");
            },
            error: function(){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Please format the code properly next time. *please let me know where is the error is* **you** have to tell us what error you get. What does *it is not working* mean? Is the Ajax request not sent? Is the callback not executed? You have to tell us what you want and what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Well one of the problems is your button is of type submit and you are not telling it to prevent the default behavior.

```
$(".logclass").click(function(e) {
   // code
   e.preventDefault();

 }
```

Next it's probably better that you use the following to call the click.

```
$('#log').click(function(e){

}
```

It's better to access by ID than class. Another option would be to change your button to something like.

```
<input type='button' id='log' class='logclass' value='log in'/>
```

That should get you started in a better direction.